# Проблема с запросом UPDATE в MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, база-данных, ms-access

У меня есть база данных, в которой имеются две (те что используются в запросе) таблицы.

Таблица Заказ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Агент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание следующее:
Напишите запрос на обновление таблицы Агент, который бы установил комиссионные агентов в размере:

- 10% от общей суммы заказов, выполненных агентами  в сентябре-октябре 2014 года, если общая сумма заказов не превышает 350000 рублей;
- 15% от общей суммы заказов, выполненных агентами  в сентябре-октябре 2014 года, если общая сумма заказов превышает 350000 рублей;
- надбавку в размере 5000 рублей тем агентам, которые имеют заказчиков с рейтингом 70 и выше.

И вот возникла проблема

Запрос:

UPDATE Агент SET Комиссионные = (SELECT SUM(Сумма) FROM Заказ AS Результат WHERE ID_Агент = Агент.ID_Агент) * 0.1 WHERE  (SELECT SUM(Сумма) FROM Заказ AS Результат WHERE ID_Агент = Агент.ID_Агент) <= 350000;

Ошибка: В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос!

При этом если я устанавливаю фиксированный размер комиссионных то все нормально работает. Но мне нужен процент от суммы заказов агента. Помогите, не могу разобраться как это реализовать.

Comment: Что есть Агент2?

Comment: @msi случайно осталось, была временная таблица, удалил чтобы не заморачиваться с описанием здесь